# Convergence theorems for $\mathcal{L}^p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Do the MCT, DCT and Fatou's lemma extend to $\mathcal{L}^p$ spaces also for $ 1 \leq p \leq \infty$. If they do not what are cases that they would fail and why?

Any help with this question is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $L^p$ when $0<p<\infty$, yes.

For $L^\infty$. For instance, in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, consider the sequence
$$
f_n=1_{(-n,n)}.
$$
It converges pointwise to $f=1$. It is dominated by $1$ which is in $L^\infty$. But
$$
\|f_n-1\|_\infty=1\qquad\forall n\geq 1
$$
does not converge to $0$. So there is no Dominated Convergence Theorem here. But Fatou and the Monotone Convergence Theorem still hold.

Comment: So the MCT and Fatou hold for $p = \infty$?

Comment: @pondy Yes, I've checked. The only problem is that we have no linearity here, so the Reverse Fatou Lemma does not hold. And that's the key in DCT.